# Why my transaction() function doesn't work? in my case I want to increase my klik data

Tags: firebase, react-native

How to increment my klik data?

```js
 klik = async() => {

     var ref = await firebase.database().ref('/listPenerbangan/001/-MeFcuKWWE62PCvhJysB/klik')
     ref.transaction(function(klik) {
         return klik + 1
     })
 }
```

Here is an image of my Firebase Realtime Database:

[image: Screenshot of Firebase Realtime Database]

Answer (score 0):

On this line, you create a reference to a location in your database:

```js
var ref = await firebase.database().ref('/listPenerbangan/001/-MeFcuKWWE62PCvhJysB/klik')
```

As this line isn't asynchronous, [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) isn't needed here and you should use [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)/[`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of `var` where possible in modern JavaScript.

```js
const ref = firebase.database()
    .ref('/listPenerbangan/001/-MeFcuKWWE62PCvhJysB/klik')
```

On the next line:

```js
ref.transaction(function(klik) {
    return klik + 1
})
```

You start a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction) ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions)) but don't listen for its result (which is a `Promise<{ committed: boolean, snapshot: DataSnapshot | null }>`).

```js
// ⬇⬇ return added here to let the caller of `klik()` handle errors
return ref.transaction(function (klik) {
    // klik may be null! (parent document doesn't exist?)
    // even though `null + 1 == 1`, you might want to do something
    return klik + 1;
})
```

Which ends up with:

```js
klik = async () => {
    const ref = firebase.database()
        .ref('/listPenerbangan/001/-MeFcuKWWE62PCvhJysB/klik');
    return ref.transaction(function(klik) {
       return klik + 1
    });
}
```

or the simpler:

```js
klik = async () => {
    return firebase.database()
        .ref('/listPenerbangan/001/-MeFcuKWWE62PCvhJysB/klik')
        .transaction(klik => klik + 1);
}
```

---

Because you are only incrementing a value, you can cut out the transaction by using a [`ServerValue.increment()` instruction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue#increment) ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments)) instead to make the change on the server itself:

```js
klik = async () => {
   return firebase.database()
       .ref('/listPenerbangan/001/-MeFcuKWWE62PCvhJysB/klik')
       .set(firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1));
}
```

---

If `klik` is the event handler for a button, you should make sure to handle the  success or failure of the database write in the handler for `klik`:

```js
const addKlik = async () => {
    return firebase.database()
        .ref('/listPenerbangan/001/-MeFcuKWWE62PCvhJysB/klik')
        .set(firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1));
}

klik = () => {
    return addKlik()
        .then(() => {
            // klik added, do something?
            // (or remove this `.then()`)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            // TODO: handle errors better than this
            console.error("klik failed: ", err);
            alert("klik failed! " + (err.code || err.message));
        });
}
```